# sbcl / CLOS Why do I have to add a "validate-superclass"-Method here?

Tags: common-lisp, clos, mop

In SBCL, when I define new metaclass

```
CL-USER> (defclass counting-class (standard-class)
   ((counter :initform 0)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS COUNTING-CLASS>
```

and add a method to the GF "make-instance":

```
CL-USER> (defmethod make-instance :after ((class counting-class) &key)
   (incf (slot-value class 'counter)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD MAKE-INSTANCE :AFTER (COUNTING-CLASS) {25302219}>
```

I receive an error, if I try to create an Instance:

```
CL-USER> (defclass counted-point () (x y) (:metaclass counting-class))

The class #<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-OBJECT> was specified as a
super-class of the class #<COUNTING-CLASS COUNTED-POINT>, but
the meta-classes #<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS> and
#<STANDARD-CLASS COUNTING-CLASS> are incompatible.  Define a
method for SB-MOP:VALIDATE-SUPERCLASS to avoid this error.
```

Now, if I add the required Definition:

```
CL-USER>  (defmethod sb-mop:validate-superclass ((class counting-class)
                                                 (super standard-class))
            t)
#<STANDARD-METHOD SB-MOP:VALIDATE-SUPERCLASS (COUNTING-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS) {26443EC9}>
```

It works:

```
CL-USER> (defclass counted-point () (x y) (:metaclass counting-class))
#<COUNTING-CLASS COUNTED-POINT>
```

My Question is: Why is this required?

From my POV it should be sufficient, to declare counting-class as an derivative of standard-class, as I did in the first step.

Answer (score 9):

[CLOS MOP](http://www.alu.org/mop/) spec for [validate-superclass](http://www.alu.org/mop/dictionary.html#validate-superclass) says that the default method returns `t` only in trivial cases and adds:

> Defining a method on `validate-superclass` requires detailed knowledge
>   of of the internal protocol followed by each of the two class
>   metaobject classes. A method on `validate-superclass` which returns true
>   for two different class metaobject classes declares that they are
>   compatible.

You could consider your `validate-superclass` to be a declaration that you understand what you are doing.

Incidentally, I think you can define [a class which would count its instances](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/mop-classes.html#class-prototype) easier.

PS. [Some implementations also return `t` in some other cases](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/mop-classes.html#validate-superclass).

Comment: Thank you,sds! But could there be a more technical reason? CLISP, for example, does not need the additional method.

Comment: the "technical reason" is in the spec: "... requires detailed knowledge of of the internal protocol ..."

Comment: The point is to understand metaclasses, not to make a class to count instances. A counted-class is the first example of a metaclass given in AMOP.